# Characteristic timescale of a can of beer?

Tags: thermal-conductivity

Modelling a 440 ml can of beer by Newton's law of cooling, the temperature difference between the can and its surroundings (e.g. a fridge) decays exponentially in time at a rate determined by the e-folding time or "characteristic timescale".

Ideally, this characteristic timescale would be determined by experimentation to give the best approximation for a particular environment (fridge). In the absence of necessary equipment to perform the experiment, can the characteristic timescale be estimated to reasonable accuracy from first principles?

Comment: The time to get good and cold is always longer than the time available between buying the beer and the first guests showing up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Modelling a 440 ml can of beer by Newton's law of cooling, the
> temperature difference between the can and its surroundings (e.g. a
> fridge) decays exponentially in time at a rate determined by the
> e-folding time or "characteristic timescale".

It's worth noting that Newton's Law of Cooling is essentially an approximation in which *internal conduction* is assumed to be absent and the temperature of the object is uniform at all times.

The Law states:

$$\dot{\mathrm{q}}=hA[T(t)-T_{\infty}]$$
where $T_{\infty}$ is the environment's (assumed constant) temperature and $T_0$ the initial temperature of the object.

Developed:
$$-mc_p\frac{\mathrm{d}T(t)}{\mathrm{d}t}=hA[T(t)-T_{\infty}]$$
This ODE is separable and on integration yields:
$$\ln\Big[\frac{T(t)-T_{\infty}}{T_0-T_{\infty}}\Big]=-\frac{t}{\tau}$$
with:
$$\tau=\frac{mc_p}{hA}$$
where $1/\tau$ is the *characteristic time*.

Sometimes, the dimensionless group:
$$\frac{T(t)-T_{\infty}}{T_0-T_{\infty}}$$
is referred to as the *reduced temperature* $\Theta$, so we get:
$$\ln\Theta=-\frac{t}{\tau}$$
Or:
$$\Theta=\exp{(-t/\tau)}$$
In $\tau$, $m$, $c_p$ and $A$ are usually accurately known. But $h$, the *convective heat transfer coefficient* (aka the 'film coefficient') is not as straightforward to determine.

The determination of $h$ can be made empirically, from specialist tables or from theory.

The convective heat transfer coefficient $h$ can be calculated from the dimensionless number $\mathrm{Nu}$, the *Nusselt number* as follows:

$$h=\frac{\mathrm{Nu}k}{L}$$

where $k$ is the thermal conductivity and $L$ a characteristic length.

For some more information on this topic, see [this page e.g.](https://www.engineersedge.com/thermodynamics/convective_heat_transfer.htm)

There's also this **excellent ebook** on Heat Transfer [that goes into great detail regarding the 'film coefficient'](https://ahtt.mit.edu/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/AHTTv500.pdf). See Ch.3, p.269.

Comment: "internal conduction is assumed to be absent" -- don't you mean internal conduction is assumed to be infinitely rapid?

Comment: @nanoman Not necessarily. If $k$ is very small there is no conduction. That's why I'm not specifying.

Comment: But $k$ in your answer is the conductivity of the ambient medium (air), which is not what I'm referring to. "Internal conduction" at the beginning of your answer refers to the conductivity of the object (beer), which should be *large* in the Newton cooling model so that, as you say, its temperature is "uniform at all times" and it cools as a monolith with heat capacity $c_p$. If internal conduction were instead "absent", only an infinitesimal skin of the object would cool.

Comment: @nanoman $k$ doesn't feature in my answer (except for estimating $h$). The $k$ I'm referring to in my comment is that of the can's content. The case of 'no-conduction' arises when no temperatures exist in the object: i.o.w. its temperature is uniform.

Comment: A large internal conductivity will indeed result in small internal temperature gradients, but the internal *heat flux* will not become small -- heat must still be transferred from the interior to the surface at the rate $\dot{\mathrm{q}}$. So even if by "conduction" you mean the heat flux, I disagree with calling it "absent" when the temperature is (nearly) uniform. On the other hand, if $k$ (of the object) is very small, the object's surface will quickly reach ambient temperature but the interior will take a long time to cool, i.e., internal temperature gradients will be large.

Answer (score 1):

No, because this timescale is dependent on the material inside and outside the can.

The can will lose heat to the environment by radiation and conduction from its surface.  The rate at which this occurs is dependent on the colour of the surface (dark surfaces are more effective radiators) and the rate at which heat is transferred from the body of the can to the surface. In the case of a real can, the outside edges will start to cool first, which will set up convection currents within the beer, transferring heat from the interior to the surface.

Finally the effects of the air in conducting and convecting heat away from the can need to be considered.

For the case of a spherical perfectly black body in a vacuum with perfect interior heat conduction, the rate of heat loss can be calculated. For real cans of beer, an empirical approach is best.  (45 minutes is enough to chill most drinks to close to fridge temperatures https://www.omnicalculator.com/food/chilled-drink)

Comment: *No, because this timescale is dependent on the material inside and outside the can.* Nonsense, I've modeled far more complex systems, with success. As regards the colour of the can that plays almost zero part because at RT/fridge temps radiative loss is negligible.